# Linq Query using Contains and not contains

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I am trying to fetch records from database in the sense that
it should getrecords where name contains "searchKey" and name not in the excludeTerms array with comma seperated.
How can I do this in Linq?

```
 Rows = (from u in DB.Clients
         where u.Name.Contains(searchTerm) && !u.Name.Contains(string.Join(",", excludeTerms.Select(s => "'" + s + "'").ToArray()))
         select new ClientModel
         {
            Name = u.FullName,
            Id = u.Id,
         }).Take(5).ToList();
```

Where excludeTerms contains list of elements, such as

```
1)Sandy
2)Mandy
3)Larry etc
```

---

```
List<string> excludeTerms = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately you can use local sequences only with Contains operator (which is translated into SQL IN operator). So, you can move whole filtering to memory

```
Rows = (from u in DB.Clients.AsEnumerable()
        where u.Name.Contains(searchTerm) &&
             !excludeTerms.Any(s => u.Name.Contains(s))
         select new ClientModel {
              Name = u.FullName,
              Id = u.Id,
         }).Take(5).ToList();
```

Or just filtering out excluded terms:

```
Rows = (from u in DB.Clients
        where u.Name.Contains(searchTerm)                 
        select new ClientModel {
              Name = u.FullName,
              Id = u.Id,
        }).AsEnumerable()
          .Where(m => !excludeTerms.Any(s => m.Name.Contains(s)))
          .Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is "s" in the above query?

Comment: @Sweetie `s` is the item in excludeTerms collection. So `!excludeTerms.Any(s => u.Name.Contains(s))` means items where none of excluded terms is contained in client's name