# Check if field contains any item from collection in LinqToSql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have next query

```
var query = (from titles in db.Titles
                join ratings in db.Ratings on titles.Rating equals ratings.Rating1
                join synopsis in db.Synopsis on titles.Certificate equals synopsis.Certificate into items
                from item in items.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where titles.Rating_Release_Date >= DateTime.Parse(fromDate) &&
                    titles.Certificate < 1000000 &&
                    platformElements.Any(r => titles.Platforms.Contains(r))  && //here i get error Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.
                    ratingElements.Any(r => titles.Rating.Contains(r))
                orderby titles.Rating_Release_Date descending, titles.Submission_Title
                select new {...}
```

But i get error when i try to check if field (titles.Platforms) contain any item from collection.

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

And now i don't know how to make where-clause correctly. 
First idea - in loop check if Platforms contains item from list, but also don't know how to implement it.

I found this article [How do I use LINQ Contains(string[]) instead of Contains(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring) but i don't think that custom extension will work in my case. Other answers is like this : `platformElements.Contains(titles.Platforms)` which isn't what i need.

---

Type of `titles.Platforms` is `string`.
Type of `platformElements` is `string[]`;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567223/linq-query-using-contains-and-not-contains

Comment: @user3444160, in my case it isn't good solution cause where-clause make huge work in filtering as i have much data

Answer (score 1):

I didn't compile it, but it should be compilable.

New class PredicateBuilder:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { 
        return f => false; 
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2) {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

New function:

```
public IQueryable<Title> FilterByPlatforms(this IQueryable<Title> titles, string[] platformElements) {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Title>();

        foreach (string platformElement in platformElements) {
            string temp = platformElement;
            predicate = predicate.Or(t => t.Platforms.Contains(temp));
        }
        return titles.Where(predicate);
    }
```

Modified query:

```
var query = (from titles in db.Titles.FilterByPlatforms(platformElements)
            join ratings in db.Ratings on titles.Rating equals ratings.Rating1
            join synopsis in db.Synopsis on titles.Certificate equals synopsis.Certificate into items
            from item in items.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where titles.Rating_Release_Date >= DateTime.Parse(fromDate) &&
                titles.Certificate < 1000000 &&
                // platformElements.Any(r => titles.Platforms.Contains(r))  && //here i get error Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.
                ratingElements.Any(r => titles.Rating.Contains(r))
            orderby titles.Rating_Release_Date descending, titles.Submission_Title
            select new {...}
```

Maybe for ratingElements you should do the same.

Source: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx